# Check if object exists in array excluding specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to check if an object exists in an array while excluding one property? I don't know which properties will exist in the object so I can't compare properties manually.

Based on the code below, I would want to check if `obj` exists in `arr` excluding `prop3`.

Example:

```
const obj = {
  "prop1": "value1",
  "prop2": "value2"
}

const arr = [{
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "prop3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "prop1": "value4",
    "prop2": "value5",
    "prop3": "value6"
  }
]
```

`arr.indexOf(obj) > -1; // returns false, need something like this that returns true`

Comment: You need to compare all the props from obj and find? What if there are more props in obj, which are not part of arr?

Comment: For my case, there will not be more props in obj which are not part of arr. Only more props in arr that are not part of obj.

Comment: Updated the answer. Will remove for loop and update with better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) & [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like so:

```js
const obj = {
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2"
}

const arr = [{
    "prop1": "value1",
    "prop2": "value2",
    "prop3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "prop1": "value4",
    "prop2": "value5",
    "prop3": "value6"
  }
]

const index = arr.findIndex(item => {
  // For every item of array:
  // - Iterate over obj keys
  // - If every k/v pair of obj matches a k/v pair of item
  //   then it's a match
  return Object.keys(obj).every(key => item[key] === obj[key])
})

console.log(index)
```

Although if you just want to know if it exists or not, you should use `Array.some` instead of `Array.findIndex`.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect because it is helpful for me to know the index of the object as well.

Answer (score 0):

User Array.findIndex() method to find index:

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
arr.findIndex((o) => {
  return keys.every(k => o[k] && o[k] === obj[k])
});
```

Comment: Can you tell the reason for the down voting?